# Modify(not Replace) ConcurrentDictionary Value

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I am using a ConcurrentDictionary which contains a string key and value of a type which contains properties.

I want to update some properties of a value in thread-safe manner. I have searched a lot but could not find any solution relating to this specific problem.

There are methods like TryUpdate and AddOrUpdate, but they essentially replace the previous value with a new one.

What would be the best way to set the property of value without replacing it?

I think it should be done like this :

```
ValueType oldVal = dict[key];
ValueType newVal = oldVal;
if (condition)
{
    newVal.prop1 = foo;
    newVal.prop2 = bar;
}
if (dict.TryUpdate(key, newVal, oldVal) == true)
    Success;
else
    Failure; //Another thread modified value first
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you include an [mcve] in your question? I think simply using the `TryGetValue(key, var value)` and then doing `value.Foo = "Bar"` should work. But without an example there is no way to know

Comment: If you want to change the property of a dictionary entry just get the entry via TryGetValue and set the property. A ConcurrentDictionary like every other ConcurrentCollection only guarantees the thread-safety of the collection – it does not guarantee the thread-safety of the objects it holds. If you want to update the properties of the dictionaries values in a thread-safe manner you need to provide the ability to do so on your own, using locks, SpinWaits, or whatever means apply best for your use-case.

Comment: @ckuri : Can you share an example, or maybe a link etc. I just want to be sure so that I don't end up locking the whole dictionary but just the value.